# Generating last modified file dates in a PHP-made folder files index

Tags: date, last-modified

I'm using a php-generated simplified index of the contents of a folder, but I fail at adding the display of the last modified date.

He's my original working code :

```
<?php
foreach (glob("*.*") as $filename) {
    echo "<a href='".$filename."'>".$filename."</a>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; - &nbsp; &nbsp; ".intval(filesize($filename) / (1024 * 1024))."MB<br>"; 
}
?>
```

What I want is to add the last modified date for each file.

But I get the zero-date (31-12-1969), meaning my code FAILS at recognizing it has to work with each file of the index :

```
<?php
foreach (glob("*.*") as $filename) {
echo "Last modified " . date("l, dS F, Y @ h:ia", $last_modified);
    echo "<a href='".$filename."'>".$filename."</a>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; - &nbsp; &nbsp; ".intval(filesize($filename) / (1024 * 1024))."MB<br>"; 
}
?>
</p>
```

Would you know how I could fix it ? Thank you VERY MUCH if you can help :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure `$last_modified` is being set at all? You might want to use [filemtime()](http://php.net/filemtime) to get the last modified date.

Resulting code:

```
<?php
foreach (glob("*.*") as $filename) {
echo "Last modified " . date("l, dS F, Y @ h:ia", filemtime($filename)) . '<br />';
    echo "<a href='".$filename."'>".$filename."</a>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; - &nbsp; &nbsp; ".intval(filesize($filename) / (1024 * 1024))."MB<br>"; 
}
?>
```

Comment: EXCELLENT ! Thank you very much, I'm truly grateful ! :)

Comment: Just an FYI, if they answered the question correctly, you should give it an upvote and mark it as the answer.